# Can I navigate in a 3D scene in A-Frame using a touch gestures?

Tags: aframe

Is it posible to navigate in a A-Frame 3D scene using touch gestures in a smartphone? As far as I know you can look to the right and the left, but how can you go forward and backward if you have not WASD keys in a phone? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but A-Frame does not come with such controls out of the box. You could implement your own components that implement locomotion by a pinch gesture, a virtual on screen joystick, using device tilt to move forward / backward...

Comment: Thanks @DiegoMarcos. I'm thinking in implementing  Z-axis navigation using long press on touch screen. I believe there is something like that somewhere on the internet with mouse-onclick. If I build a component, I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

The `universal-controls` component in [aframe-extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras) will let you long-press to move forward. To go backward you would need to turn around. Teleportation ([example](http://sandbox.donmccurdy.com/checkpoints)) may be a better option on mobile devices.

Comment: Many Thanks, @Don McCurdy. I'm trying `universal-controls`. By the way I get build errors when importing it in a component. It seems there is a dependency that is coded in es6 but it should be exposed as es5 module (as say in create-react-app docs). I have to import it in `index.html` using a <script> tag. I think to remember it is `utils.js` in a node module called `three-someting`. Excuse me, I dont remember the exact name. Just mentioning it for anyone having this problem.

Comment: Could you [file a bug](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/issues/new) with more information about the error? GitHub issues are better than Stack Overflow for that type of question.

Comment: Sure, i was thinking on it. I'll open a issue in the repo.

Comment: After a few days working I can' t reproduce the error. It seems I was importing both `aframe-extras` and also `aframe-extras.loaders`.That could be the cause of the error. Now it seems enough just to import `aframe-extras.loaders` to import a json 3d model. Hope to have been clear. Cheers.